# Layout constraints for custom UITtableViewCell not working

Tags: swift, uitableview, uilabel, constraints

I'm creating custom UITableViewCells with a UILabel in each but can't get the label to display anywhere else than the top left corner of the cell, [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuFWM.png).

Constraints don't seem to be applied yet they're being called (reaching breakpoint). I tried to replace the UILabel by an UIImageView and apply the same constraints but nothing appears (i.e. table view cells are blank).

What am I missing?

View for cells:

```
import UIKit

class myTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
    }

    let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: UIFontWeightLight)
        label.text = "Sample"
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return label
    }()

    func setupViews () {
        addSubview(label)
        //add constraints
        let marginsGuide = self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginsGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginsGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginsGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

}
```

View controller:

```
import UIKit

class myViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

    var myTableView: UITableView = UITableView()

    var myArray = [Int]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //... do stuff incl. loading data into my myArray
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        self.myTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)
        self.myTableView.delegate = self
        self.myTableView.dataSource = self
        self.myTableView.register(IngredientListTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        self.view.addSubview(myTableView)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! myTableViewCell
        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
addSubview(label)
```

to this

```
contentView.addSubview(label)
```

Comment: Works. Noticed self.contentView.addSubview(label) also works. Could you help me understand what's happening?

Comment: In a table view cell, always use the content view. The view is there for the content of the cell. Hence the name. Your code didn't work because you used the margins of the content view (`let marginsGuide = self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide`) but added the subview to the cell itself.